# Extract a text from a line or string using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep

I have below data in my text file. I know how to loop through the line in shell script. Just need help in understanding how will I take out only **ABC or TES or HYJ or  VVB** line by line from the below strings in a file.

```
!abc { xyz: "ABC", queue: "TEST" },
!abc { xyz: "TES", queue: "TEST" },
!abc { xyz: "HYJ", queue: "TEST" },
!abc { xyz: "VVB", queue: "TEST" },
```

The format of the above data will remain same..

I have tried this below suggestion

```
#!/bin/bash

line1="!abc { xyz: "ABC", queue: "TEST" },"
echo $line1
test_data=$(echo $line1 | grep -Eoh '!abc { xyz: ".*?"' | cut -d\" -f3)
echo $test_data
```

For the above code nothing is getting outputted.

Expected Output should be test_data = **ABC**
If we do "echo $test_data" it should give me ABC

Comment: please **update the question** with the code you've tried, the (wrong) output generated by your code, and the (correct) expected output, making sure the outputs correspond to the provided sample input

Comment: Try this `awk -F\" '{print $2}' your_file`

Comment: one issue: you're storing the results of the `echo/grep/cut` call in a variable named `test_data` but then printing the content of a different variable named `$acct_no`; as for what's being stored in `test_data` ... hard to tell if it's right or wrong as we (still) don't know what the (correct) expected output is

Comment: @markp-fuso : i updated my code it was typo

Comment: @markp-fuso OFS is not needed.  FS is set  `-F\"`

Comment: Thnaks you @ufopilot it wrok with file but i want the same thing done on a string variable.
Other then file if i want to extract the same thing if it was passed in a variable like given below:


line1="!abc { xyz: "ABC", queue: "TEST" },"
can we do 
awk -F\" '{print $2}' $line1

Comment: @MoshinHilalKondkari
 `awk -F\" '{print $2}' <<<"$line1"`  Salam

Comment: @ufopilot walekum as salam it worked for me.
just one last help can we store this result in a variable.

Comment: @MoshinHilalKondkari `var=$(awk -F\" '{print $2}' <<<"$line1")`

Answer (score 1):

Good day,

how about the cut command: $cut -d'"' -f2 file.txt

which cut out the second field with delimiter '"' .

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this, here is one, that is really simple:

1. cat file.txt prints out the contents of the file
2. AWK is used to divide the line into two parts, one prior to ":" and another one after it.
3. Another AWK command is being used to divide the resulting output into two parts again, one before "," and one after it
4. Lastly SED command is used to remove the double quotes ""

   cat file.txt | awk -F ":" '{print $2}' | awk -F "," '{print $1}' | sed -e 's/"//' -e 's/"$//'

Comment: sed: `sed -E 's/(^[^"]*")(\w+)(".*)/\2/' file.txt`